# In EazyBi, How can I do a substring of a dimension name

Tags: jira, mdx, jira-plugin

I have a dimension that has this structure :, example: JIRA-525:Ticket Summary.

I'd like to extract the second part, but with no positive result.
I tried to create a custom field on that dimension and do a string operation, I know this won't give me expected result, but a basic string function is not working, as the grid is showing errors:

```
left([Concept].CurrentMember.Name,10)
```

What should I do differentñy?

Comment: why dont you add summary as a property to your source data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message could give us some hints on what is wrong here. If you created a new calculated measure with the formula, it should return results.

Define a new calculated measure (measure not member, sometimes people mix them up) with the formula below:

```
[Concept].CurrentMember.AllProperties
```

Does that return any results with the dimension on rows? Does it have a "Name" property?

Ultimately, I would suggest creating a new calculated measure with *ExtractString()* function - https://docs.eazybi.com/eazybi/analyze-and-visualize/calculated-measures-and-members/mdx-function-reference/extractstring. But first see what properties are available.

If you are looking to change the dimension member names, then that can be done only with JavaScript calculated custom fields - https://docs.eazybi.com/eazybijira/data-import/custom-fields/javascript-calculated-custom-fields.